# Can my national Bank use a IRS refund deposit to reopen a inactive account and then use the money to pay on a charged off mortgage

Tags: united-states, bank-account, irs

My accountant accidentally deposited my IRS refund in to a old inactive bank account.  The bank reopened the account and used the deposit to pay on a. Charged off mortgage. Can they do this

Comment: I think no, but that should be your accountant's problem, right? He is supposed to give you your money, and if he accidentially gave it to his niece and she bought icecream from it, it would he _his_ problem, right? So what changes if he gave it to the wrong bank account?? Sound to me like a hair-brained excuse for embezzling funds.

Comment: @Aganju, this is OPs bank account, it's just an account that hasn't been in use, likely because the mortgage was delinquent.  I can't speak to the legality of the bank appropriating the funds but this doesn't scream embezzlement to me, and it's hardly the accountant's problem is there was no notice of a new bank account.

Comment: I understood that, but it says 'accidentally' - I interpreted this as the accountants accident (or claim). I see now it could be interpreted differently.

Comment: Did the bank issue you a 1099-C for the cancelled debt, or is the term "charged off" looser, in a sense of "inactive", in this scenario?

Comment: What do you mean by "national bank"?